# Google+ Sign-in button does not always load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-plus

I have the following Javascript on the bottom of my `index.html`:

```
<script>
  function signInCallback(authResult) {
    if (authResult.code && authResult.access_token) {
      if (authResult['g-oauth-window']) {
        $.post('/auth/google/callback', {code: authResult.code, access_token: authResult.access_token}).done
          (function(data) {
            window.location.href = data.redir;
          });
      }
    }
  };

  (function() {
    $('#button-address').tooltip();
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript';
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

...as well as this HTML in the template of an Angular directive:

```
<div id="signinButton">
  <span
    class="g-signin"
    data-scope="email"
    data-clientid="CLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    data-redirecturi="postmessage"
    data-accesstype="offline"
    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
    data-callback="signInCallback">
  </span>
</div>
```

This code renders a Google+ sign-in button on my Angular app's sign-in page. The problem is ~30% of the time the button does not render and the user needs to refresh the page until it appears. I believe this occurs because sometimes the `#signinButton` div has not been rendered before the JS is run. Does this sound like it could be the issue, and if so how can I delay the JS running until the `#signinButton` div has been rendered to assure the button always appears?

Comment: maby manualy call gapi.signin2.render('signinButton' , options)
after the html is there

Comment: script is at body bottom right?

Comment: @Sebastian, it is yes

Comment: @Sebastian, added details noting where that script block is located and also pointing out that my HTML is located within the template of an Angular directive.

Comment: Direct DOM manipulation in an angular application is playing with fire, because you're outside the `$digest` loop.  Put this functionality in the directive that draws `#signinButton` instead of just dumping it at the end of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify this to work within Angular's lifecycle:  `document.ready` is when Angular *starts* setting up the DOM, not when it's finished. Depending on `document.ready` or just dropping code in at the end of the page sets up a  potential race condition because there is no guarantee that the DOM node you want to attach events to exists yet (it'll only work if the injected script's load time takes long enough for Angular to have finished rendering by the time the script arrives. Which means on any but the first, non-cached visit it's guaranteed *not* to work.)

Assuming the script at `client:plusone.js` expects to see an existing DOM node `#signinButton` when linked, you can ensure that the node will exist by including it as part of the directive that renders `#signinButton`:

```
var app = angular.module("foo", []);
app.directive('signinButton', function($timeout) {
  return {
    template: '<div id="signinButton">...etc...</div>',
    link: function() {
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      var url = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
      if (s.src !== url) { /* Don't re-insert the script if it's already there */
        $timeout(function() { // force this to run in the next $digest, after the directive template is rendered
          var po = document.createElement('script');
          po.type = 'text/javascript';
          po.async = true;
          po.src = url;
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

(The callback function isn't time-sensitive; it can stay at the end of the document as you have now, since that's apparently where `client:plusone.js` expects to find it, or you could also attach it to the window object from within the directive.)

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an AngularJS application why don't you use a directive like this one: [angular-directive.g-signin](https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin)
?
The example is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score -1):

put it your function call in `$(document).ready()` maybe solves your problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button-address').tooltip();
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript';
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})
```

Comment: This code block is already at the very bottom of my `index.html` which I believe accomplishes the same thing as `$(document).ready`.